# Objective c algorithm to import addressbook with many contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, addressbook, abaddressbook

my app read Iphone AddressBook and for each contact get email and phone numbers. After that process i save this info into my database and build an object that i store in NSMutableArray for next purpose. I execute this operation only the first time user launch the app. When i have small AddressBook ( < 500 contacts ) this work like a charme and i have a reasonable waiting time ( about 1 minutes ) , but with large number of contacts ( > 2000 ) i have an excessive waiting time and bad performance ( about 3,4 minutes ). Although this task is carried out in a background thread, there is any way to optimize this stage of import (maybe importing multiple contacts at a time?).

This is my code for launch Import process:

```
-(void)importaContatti:(int32_t)lastIDContatto {

    [self beginBackgroundUpdateTask:&importContattiTaskIdentifier];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook;    

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 6.0) {        
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);        
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook,
                                             ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error){
                                                 dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                                             });

            dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   } else {        
      addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
   }

   CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
   CFIndex nPeople      = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

   if(nPeople == 0) {
      [[Database getIstance]insertBGPhoneData:@"importContatti" val:@"1"];
      CFRelease(addressBook);
      [self endBackgroundUpdateTask:&importContattiTaskIdentifier];
      return;
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ ) {        
       ABRecordRef ref  = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
       int32_t idIphone = ABRecordGetRecordID(ref);
       if(idIphone <= lastIDContatto) {
           continue;
       }        
       Contatto *c = [Contatto buildContattoFromRubricaIphone:&ref];        
       CFRelease(ref);        
       c = NULL;        
       [[Database getIstance]insertBGPhoneData:@"lastImportContatto" val:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", idIphone ]];

   }

   [[Database getIstance]insertBGPhoneData:@"importContatti" val:@"1"];
   if(allPeople) {
       CFRelease(allPeople);
   }

  [self endBackgroundUpdateTask:&importContattiTaskIdentifier];    
}
```

And this is a code for import Process:

```
+(Contatto *)buildContattoFromRubricaIphone:(ABRecordRef *)ref {
    int32_t idIphone    = ABRecordGetRecordID(*ref);    
    Contatto *c         = [Contatto create];    
    CFStringRef nome    = ABRecordCopyValue(*ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    CFStringRef cognome = ABRecordCopyValue(*ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *alias     = [[Utils getIstance]buildAlias:(__bridge NSString *)nome cognome:(__bridge NSString *)cognome];

    c.rubrica2 = [Rubrica2 build:0 idIphone:idIphone alias:alias img:NULL stato:ATTIVO jidPreferito:0 mergedWith:0 imgUpdated:0 personalStatus:0 xmppStatus:@"" xmppMood:NESSUNO xmppDisponibilita:@""];
    if(nome) {        
        CFRelease(nome);
    }

    if(cognome) {
        CFRelease(cognome);
    }

    [c.rubrica2 save];

    Rubrica_TEL *telForAlias   = NULL;
    Rubrica_MAIL *mailForAlias = NULL;

    for(NSString *numeroTelefono in [Contatto getNumeriContattoFromRubricaIphone:ref]) {

        Rubrica_TEL *tel = [Rubrica_TEL build:0 idRubrica:c.rubrica2.ID telefono:numeroTelefono tipo:0 stato:ATTIVO prevMerged:0];

        [tel saveWithNotification:false];

        if(telForAlias == NULL) {
            telForAlias = tel;
        }

        [c add:tel];
    }

    for(NSString *stringMail in [Contatto getEmailFromRubricaIphone:ref]) {

        Rubrica_MAIL *mail = [Rubrica_MAIL build:0 rubricaID:c.rubrica2.ID mailID:stringMail mailAlias:alias];

        [mail saveWithNotification:false];

        if(mailForAlias == NULL) {
           mailForAlias = mail;
        }

        [c add:mail];
    }


    if([c.rubrica2.alias length] == 0) {

        if(telForAlias != NULL) {
            c.rubrica2.alias = telForAlias.telefono;
        } else if(mailForAlias != NULL) {
            c.rubrica2.alias = mailForAlias.mail;
        }

        if([c.rubrica2.alias length] > 0) {
            [c.rubrica2 save];
        }
    }

return c;
}
```

With this method i get the phone from addressBook contact ( email is similar ):

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getNumeriContattoFromRubricaIphone:(ABRecordRef *)ref {
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ABMultiValueRef *phones = ABRecordCopyValue(*ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);


    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++) {
        CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
        NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef;
        if(phoneNumber != NULL) {
            phoneNumber = [[Utils getIstance]formatE164:phoneNumber];
            [result addObject:phoneNumber];
        }

        if(phoneNumberRef) {
            CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
        }

    }

    if(phones) {
        CFRelease(phones);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where is your bottleneck, reading the contacts, inserting in database ...?

Comment: at this moment i need 0.11 seconds to elaborate each contact. I'd like to optimize this process to reduce this time and speed up the import process.

Comment: Try using dispatch_apply for performing for loop actions. It makes your code run more concurrently.

Comment: Hi Pasquale, I am in the same situation, did you find any optimised way to fetch large number of records from Address Book?